Enabling Brotli compression in Ubuntu 24.04
I'm wondering if anyone has a roadmap for implementing Brotli compression on a Ubuntu 24.04 system with NGINX 1.26.2? I have found various answers for earlier versions of Ubuntu but nothing specific to 24.04. When I try the apt commands suggested in articles for older versions they fail in various ways
One example: I found this command:
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:hda-me/nginx-stable 

which failed like this:
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/hda-me/nginx-stable/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

I think what I'm asking is can someone advise the repository containing the Brotli module that I need to add to match the version of NGINX in 24.04?
This is the current repository list if that helps, as you can see the nginx comes from the WordOps repository:
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease  
Hit:2 http://repo.netdata.cloud/repos/stable/ubuntu noble/ InRelease  
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease  
Hit:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease  
Hit:5 http://repo.netdata.cloud/repos/repoconfig/ubuntu noble/ InRelease  
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease  
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu noble InRelease  
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu noble InRelease  
Hit:10 ppa.launchpadcontent.net/wordops/nginx-wo/ubuntu noble InRelease  
Hit:8 mirror.realcompute.io/mariadb/mariadb-11.4.3/repo/ubuntu noble InRelease  


Please update your question with what you are actually doing and the results.

updated as per Soren's request

That PPA hasn't been updated since 2019 ... you can open the url (https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/hda-me/nginx-stable/ubuntu) in a browser and click into the 'dist' link to see what distributions are supported.
